# import string from different file in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Last week I installed the Telegram application on my Raspberry Pi and set up a script to send me notifications on time (with crontab). But as I have to enter a Token from my Bot and a chat_id of my Telegram Account I want to store them one time in different files so I only have to change it in one file if they ever change. So far my code looks like this:

telepot.py:

```
   import telepot
   import values

   with open("values.py", "r") as valuesFile:
   chat_id, Token = valuesFile.readlines()

   bot = telepot.Bot('TOKEN')
   bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'message')
```

values.py:

```
chat_id = 'ChatID'
Token = 'TOKEN'
```

But I haven't figured out how to get the information from my other files. I have looked on the internet but I'm not really good a programming like at all so I hoped somebody could help me with finding the right command to import the two strings from my files and use them as the declaration for chat_id and TOKEN.

Comment: Please also add to your post where you want to get the strings from. A plain text file? Another python file? HTTP? Something else?

Comment: Create a json file and add the details in there, and read the json configuration file in your program.

Comment: Well I thought to just use a text file but if it would be simpler to use another format I'd be open to this.

Comment: @AlphaInc. I believe that using another python file would be best, see my answer below for the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather unclear. Are you importing the values and tokens from a python file? A text file?. I will guide you through a few examples.

If you want to import the values from another python file (let's call it values.py and let's assume it's in the same directory as the script you sent (telepot.py))
**values.py**

```py
chat_id = 'YOUR_CHAT_ID'
TOKEN = 'YOUR_TOKEN'
```

**telepot.py**

```py
import values
import telepot

bot = telepot.Bot(values.TOKEN)
```

Now, let's assume the values you need are in a text file, values.txt that looks like: 
TOKEN 
CHAT_ID 
**telepot.txt**

```py
import telepot

with open("values.txt", "r") as valuesFile:
    chatId, Token = valuesFile.readlines()

bot = telepot.Bot(Token)
bot.sendMessage(chatId, "This is a message")
```

Comment: First Thank you for your comment. I tired your code but get an error message:

telepot.exception.BadHTTPResponse: (200, u'<html>\r\n<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n', <urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x76bde850>)

Any idea why?

Comment: That's something to do with the telpot library. Are you sure you're authenticating right? Are you passing the Token as a string or a number?

Comment: when I enter the Token and the Chat_id manually it works. When I print the lines it says this: ["'TOKEN'\n"] (of course I entered the token number, I just replaced it in the comment)

Comment: Is your code exactly like mine: does it say `chatId, Token = valuesFile.readlines()`. If you do `chatId = valuesFile.readlines()` or `token = valuesFile.readlines()` then the value will look like ["'TOKEN'\n"].

Comment: Well I tried it again and now I get the message "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Bot'"... I fully copied your code but made a few changes. I changed chatID (from teleport.py) to chat_id (to match it in the values.py) and changed values.txt to values.py... Any idea why it does want to work ?

Comment: So you're doing 
`with open("values.py", "r") as valuesFile:`?

Comment: Please can you edit your original post with your current code @AlphaInc.

Comment: So I edited my code in my original post. When I try to run the code with python I get the message I mentioned in the comment above (that module object has no attribute 'Bot')

Comment: @AlphaInc. The file is also called telepot.py, which interferes with the import of the package. Rename the file 'telepot.py' to something else, like 'mainfile.py'. If this question is solves please mark my answer as correct.
Happy Coding :D

Comment: Alright This worked :D But now I'm getting another error message: telepot.exception.BadHTTPResponse: (200, u'<html>\r\n<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n', <urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x76bc1850>)

Comment: @AlphaIbc, that's a different issue. Something to do with the telepot library. If the issue of the question is fixed please mark my answer as correct. Happy Coding :D